# scanf erases pointer value in structure (C)

Tags: pointers, scanf, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

my structures are product and supermarket.

product:

```
typedef struct product
{
    char* product_name;
    char* barcode;
} product;
```

suprmarket:

```
typedef struct super_market
{
    product** product_list;
    int number_of_products;
} super_market;
```

my main is:

```
super_market new_super;
new_super.number_of_products = 0;
new_super.product_list = (product**)malloc(MAX_NUM_PRODUCTS * sizeof(product));
if (new_super.product_list == NULL)
    printf("couldnt do malloc");

char user_barcode[12] = { 0 };
char *barcode = (char*)malloc(12);
if (barcode == NULL)
    printf("!!couldn't do malloc");;
while(user_barcode!=505){
//exit code is 505
    scanf("%s", user_barcode);
    barcode = user_barcode;
    new_super.product_list[new_super.number_of_products] = add_product(barcode);
    new_super.number_of_products++;
}
```

add_product does:

```
product* new_product = (product*)malloc(sizeof(product));
new_product->product_name = (char*)malloc(20);
if (new_product->product_name == NULL)
    printf("couldn't do malloc");

new_product->barcode = add_barcode;
printf(adding_product_name);
scanf("%s", new_product->product_name);

return new_product;
}
```

It seems that after the user has entered a second barcode(in the scanf line), the value of barcode of prod1 is deleted and replaced by the second barcode.

Also, I don't know if it matters but barcode and new_super.product_list[new_super.number_of_products]->barcode has the same address.

I'd be happy to know where is my mistake.
thanks to everyone that answers.

Comment: `user_barcode` is a character array, so `user_barcode!=505` checks whether it is at memory location 505.  That is almost surely not what you want.  What were you hoping to accomplish with that line?  Maybe `strcmp(user_barcode, "505") != 0`?

Comment: You should be getting a compiler warning for that, by the way - turn on warnings and don't ignore them!